# how to display the data that I already select from drop down menu in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysqli, drop-down-menu

May I know, how to display the sn (staff number) after I select the name from drop down menu? For example, if I select name "aziz" from drop down menu, it should be display the aziz's sn (staff number) too in the text box, which is "1001". Both name and sn (staff number) should be save into the database. Here I attach my staff table that include name and sn (staff number) and my interface of the system:
[image: staff table]

[image: my interface that I want to display after select name and display the staff number according to their name]

Below is my code:

```html
 <div class="col-md-6">
    <table width="567">
    <tr>
    <td><b><u>Equipment Details</u></b></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="146">Name:</td>
    <td width="409"><select name="staff" required>
        <option value="">--ALL--</option>
        <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT name FROM staff";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<option value=\"".$row["name"]."\"";
        if($_POST['name'] == $row['name'])
        echo 'selected';
        echo ">".$row["name"]."</option>";
        }
        ?></select></td></tr> <!--name-->
    <tr><td>SN No:</td>
    <td><?php 
    $sql = "SELECT sn FROM staff WHERE staff = '$staff'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $snnum = $row['sn'];
    }
    ?><input type="text" name="sn" value="<?php echo $snnum ?>" required></td></tr><!--sn (staff number)-->
```

Comment: no need for another round trip of searching, just add sn into the select dropdown as a data attribute and set it as value in the input text box on select change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Kevin says at comment just set data attribut `sn` to option select and use select change.
first set sn to data attribute like this

`echo '<option value="'.$row["name"].'" data-sn="'.$row["sn"].'" > '.$row["name"].' </option>';`

and i use jquery for select onchange

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('select[name$="staff"]').change(function() {
            var sn = $('select[name$="staff"]').find(':selected').data('sn');
            $('input[name$="sn"]').val(sn);
         });
     });
</script>
```

this section `$('select[name$="staff"]').change(function() {});` it will fired when select have name staff changed, and find the selected option and get data attribute `sn` and will save to `var sn` after that set the value for `input type name='sn'` with `var sn`.

the code will look like this

```html
<tr>
    <td width="146">Name:</td>
    <td width="409">
        <select name="staff"  required>
            <option value="">--ALL--</option>
            <?php 
            $sql = "SELECT name,sn FROM staff";
            $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo '<option value="'.$row["name"].'" data-sn="'.$row["sn"].'" > '.$row["name"].' </option>';
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr> <!--name-->

<tr>
    <td>SN No:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sn" value="" required></td>
</tr><!--sn (staff number)-->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select[name$="staff"]').change(function() {
            var sn = $('select[name$="staff"]').find(':selected').data('sn');
            $('input[name$="sn"]').val(sn);
        });
    });
</script>
```